# Is there an appeals process for the automatic question rate limit?

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I get this message:

> It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back
>   soon!
>
> You've asked 4 questions recently, some of which have not been
>   received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own
>   pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your
>   questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account
>   from asking questions entirely.
>
> It's been 4 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you
>   wait 2 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your
>   previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have
>   pointed out in comments.
>
> Recommended reading:
>
> - tips on asking great questions as well as our guidance on
> - which questions are allowed here
>
> Additional advice
>
> - Examining highly-scored questions in the tags that interest you is a great way to study how to ask better questions, that also get better
>     answers much sooner!
> - We don’t demand perfection, but please make sure you use proper grammar, spelling and capitalization, it really helps!
> - Improve downvoted questions rather than deleting them.
> - Do not delete your account, create new accounts, or otherwise attempt to circumvent these restrictions.
> - Do not contact us regarding these restrictions, they cannot be lifted.
>
> Failure to heed this advice may increase the severity of these
>   restrictions.
>
> For more information
>
> See: Why won’t the system allow me to ask questions for several days?
>
> It sometimes takes a few attempts at a good question in order to fully
>   learn how our system works, and what the community expects from folks
>   seeking answers. Just do your best to make sure you've improved the
>   quality of your existing questions, and we'll see you in 2 days!

It's clear the system doesn't want me here. Is there an appeal process? Is there a proxy service for asking questions so other people can take some of the heat? I didn't do anything wrong.

> This question may already have an answer here:
>
> What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting
>   questions/answers from this account”? 1 answer No, my question is
>   different. I will edit to explain how.

I explain why it is different in the comments to this question.

Comment: i don't know how to find these resources.

Comment: this page links to a page about "help vampires". one sign is "Does he clearly lack the ability or inclination to ask the almighty Google?" i search for all of my answers before asking here, and i'm frequently accused of not searching.

Comment: As you note, your message includes the following info: "It's been 4 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 2 days before asking again."  Being asked to click on links, to read the relevant FAQ's, and to wait two days before asking another question, and asking that question carefully, in no way means that "the system doesn't want" you here.

Comment: users who can't be bothered to form sentences --
users who don't do the most basic kinds of research themselves --
users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do --
i don't fall under any of these categories.

Comment: @namaste i do everything you mentioned, and i'm still not allowed to use the site. i have more than one question per week. i don't know anyone who moves that slowly. it's not human.

Comment: Let's take [this example](https://superuser.com/q/1442789/172195). Why didn't you respond to the comments that asked for clarification and make edits to resolve those raised issues?

Comment: First, the "wait two days" thing is automatic and nobody here can change it. You have a chance to change things. On the meta of the site where you got this message, ask if people can tell you what it is about your questions that were not well received. You say you don't know. Perhaps someone will tell you. THEN FIX THAT. It doesn't matter whether you think it's fair that people don't like whatever it is they don't like. If you want answers, you have to ask properly. And properly is defined site by site.

Comment: my comments are being deleted right now. if this isn't proof, there is no possible proof.

Comment: We try to help, please try to be open for what we suggest instead of assuming us being evil.

Comment: why don't you suggest something i haven't already tried? i've done all the work, i google, i read links, i spend hours doing pseudo-research busywork, all before i ask my question. i still don't get anywhere.

Comment: I thought to myself...let's take a look at the questions, even if I know absolutely nothing about programming etc. Maybe the guy needs a little help, a few words of encouragement... That is when I saw this question. Here it is in its entirety, including title, [what's the delay between keystrokes when you hold a key in windows? // microsoft windows 10 version 1803](https://superuser.com/questions/1436075/whats-the-delay-between-keystrokes-when-you-hold-a-key-in-windows)

Comment: I don't know what you already tried. I went to your network profile to work out on which site you might even get this message as you forgot to include that information in your question. So that is why I guessed it must have been on Super User, hence me leaving you a comment about that question. I get that this frustrating but we can only act on facts you provide us. Otherwise we have to leave it for the mods or Community Management team to handle.

Comment: I mean...where is the research? Where did you try first to find a resolution? When did this problem began? Is this the first time? Is it a problem?? Have you installed programmes that are not supported by microsoft? And this ME! A complete numbskull where computers are concerned! You get very little sympathy from me, and I am not an AI bot, I can assure you :)

Comment: *i've done all the work, i google, i read links, i spend hours doing pseudo-research busywork, all before i ask my question.* I can only see a limited number of questions where you are a member, so I'm thinking a number of your posts have been deleted. The ones that remain are written OKish , they get to the point quickly enough, but they don't show hardly any effort, time, or care. They seem to be very specific too, questions that might not interest anyone else, but I might be wrong there. And it's my  impression that the answers submitted to your questions show far more effort and detail.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there an appeal process?

No, there is not. The message you got is fully automated. It is triggered if your posts get down votes and/or are closed. The votes are cast by community members. Both the help centre and the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) on each site meta offer guidance on what is expected of posts. If you still need assistance do so on the per-site meta with a post where you state/list why you feel the post is okay. Members can then advice where your interpretation of what is expected from posts differs from what is actually needed.

> Is there a proxy service for asking questions so other people can take some of the heat?

No, unfortunately not easily on the SE network. We are a strictly on content moderated question and answer sites. There is guidance to put you on the right track but if you get it right is only known once you post. A few sites do have so called sandboxes but those are more to verify the layout of your post. If you have enough reputation you could try chat but not all rooms are open for these kind mentoring.

My advice would be to wait the few days out. Revisit your posts and select one you feel has the best chance to be salvageable when put in front of the users of the Meta site where you got that message. Ask for help with guidance and tips on how to improve that post so the post becomes a good fit for the site. Keep in mind that all users are willing to help, despite popular belief.

A good read:

- [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)
- [How does "proof of effort" make a question better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179035/how-does-proof-of-effort-make-a-question-better)
- [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Be warned. You're on your way to be quality banned.  That situation is explained in [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) . Please make sure you understand what that means and does to your capability to post on an site. You now still have the option to improve. Use that opportunity to the best of your ability.

Comment: Not sure why you unilaterally reopened the question.  In order to answer it? Not necessarily a "bad" thing to have done, but I think you countered the community's assessment, and added little in the way of helpful information that the OP is likely to read.

Comment: @Namaste I'm trusted with that privilege so I use it. The exact  phrasing of the message shown by the OP wasn't found on MSE. They are not yet quality banned, they are close but not there yet, so the dupe doesn't apply. They asked two specific questions which didn't had an answer on MSE either. That made that I decided an answer was better instead of adding more dupes. And of course everything for the reputastion! Flower Power!

Comment: @Namaste is there a point to this nit-picking?  Yeah, there are typos, but rene can't edit them now, so why poke at it?  If the two of you want to have a discussion, please take it to chat.

Comment: @Monica  Please be kinder in your comments, and don't single just me out for an extended conversation, as you did in your comment above.  Granted, there's likely a "club" you and rene belong to (the "elite"), but please refrain from unkind comments intended to shut a "lowly" user up.  Had you addressed both me and rene, I would not be writing this.  But there is definitely a "club meta" of some sort where "club" members get a "bye" (and even upvotes from other "club" members, but "regular members" are spoken to in a condescending and patronizing manner.

Comment: @rene took action to delete questionable comments only after I took such action with my own comments.  I'm the bigger person here, but if you insist on defaulting to support only those you consider reputable sufficiently to belong to the "club" whose members you defend or you look the other way when club members' behavior steers off track, then the entire mission of this site (meta) becomes fraudulent, as you are a mod who is supposed to remain far more objective than you have here.

Comment: @Namaste I addressed you because you were the one who *kept going* after rene (who I don't have any special connection with) said "go ahead" and tried to exit the conversation -- a conversation that you started to critique typos in comments.  I also referred to "the two of you" and rene gets pinged on every comment.  I'm not going to have a conversation with you about it here; I'm just clarifying since you might have misunderstood what happened.

Comment: Thanks, @MonicaCellio.  It slipped my mind that rene was the answerer here and that they would get pinged with your comment by default.  Thanks again.